# Porque el metodo File.delete() no funciona

Tags: java, netbeans

Llevo ya casi 2 días frustrado intentando buscar la falla de porque el metodo registro.delete() no elimina el archivo "Registro.txt". Estoy trabajando con Gui, y cada vez que le doy click a una fila de un JTable y luego click al boton "banear", no me elimina el archivo "Registro.txt", y tampoco escribe!!, sin embargo si lo hago desde otra clase, como la clase que tiene el método main(), si borra. 
Lo que queria hacer, es borrar una linea del Registro.txt, escribiendo en otro txt todas las lineas que no contenian al String nombre, y despues renombrarla al nombre Registro.txt
No se que ocurre, les dejo el extracto

```
ActionListener ban = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int fila = table.getSelectedRow();
                String nombre = (String) modelo.getValueAt(fila, 0);
                modelo.removeRow(fila);
                try {
                    removeUser(nombre);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
        btnBanear.addActionListener(ban);


  public void removeUser(String nombre) throws IOException {
        String lee = null;
        String usuario = "";
        CharSequence aux = nombre;
        try {
            registro = new File("Registro.txt");
            tempFile = new File("Registro1.txt");
            lector = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(registro));
            fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        while ((lee = lector.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(aux);
            if (lee.contains(nombre)) {
                continue;
            } else {

                writer.write(lee);

            }
        }
        lector.close();
        fw.close();
        writer.close();
        registro.delete();
```

Comment: trata con File.Delete(registro);

Comment: File o Files? porque son 2 librerias diferentes

Comment: System.IO.File.Delete() 
el metodo estático de la clase, no el del objeto

Comment: En la API, la clase File no tiene metodos estaticos, la clase Files si

Comment: estas usando C#? en que framework estas ?  System.IO.File.Delete("Registro.txt"); debería funcionar

Comment: viendolo mas de cerca, tu problema parece ser el uso de paths relativos en lugar de absolutos, tendrás que utilizar la ruta absoluta de donde quieres crear el archivo para que funcione; la ruta absoluta es lo que contiene C:\archivo\etc\etc\etc\

Comment: Estoy usando Java, no C#

Comment: pfff, no se por que esto me aparecio en búsquedas de c#, mil disculpas por quitarte tu tiempo